# Finding the image of $f(x):=\tan^{-1}(x+1)+ \cot^{-1}(x)$ without derivatives and limits

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, trigonometry

> It is given
>   $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$
>   $$f(x):=\tan^{-1}(x+1)+ \cot^{-1}(x)$$
>   $\mathcal R_f=?$

So far, I've learned $\tan$ and $\cot$ are complementary functions, therefore
$$\tan^{-1}(x) + \cot^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

I entered a loop using $$\tan(x) =\frac{1}{\cot(x)}\;.$$

Can I use $\tan$ for the whole expression and from there on use the $\tan$ addition formula?

> Is there a way of finding the image without using derivatives and limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Combine the complementarity identity in the question with the arctangent addition identity
$$\arctan u \pm \arctan v = \arctan\frac{u \pm v}{1 \mp uv} \pmod \pi .$$ (I'm not sure that this approach avoids limits in the strict sense, since finding the range of the resulting function requires knowing about the asymptotic behavior of $\arctan$.)

Comment: this formula turned out to be very useful. At the very end we get: $$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\;+\;\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\Big)$$ The expression in the denominator is always (strictly) positive so, in order to get the maximum value of $f(x)$, I used the $y_0$ value of the vertex of the parabola by the formula instead of derivative. The result is: $$f(\mathbb R)=\Big\langle\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\;+\;\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)\Big\rangle$$

Comment: Great, this looks mostly correct. I'm not familiar with the $\langle \cdots \rangle$ notation in this context, but $f(\Bbb R)$ includes $f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan \frac{4}{3})$, but not $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so the range is half-open: Using the complementarity identity we can rewrite $$f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan(x + 1) - \arctan x ,$$ but $\arctan$ is strictly increasing, so $\arctan(x + 1) - \arctan x$ is positive for all $x$, and thus $f(x) > \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $x$.

Comment: Also, note that $\arctan \frac{4}{3}$ can be written as $2 \arctan \frac{1}{2}$; cf. my expression for $f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ a comment under Mani's answer.

Comment: I forgot other countries use '(' & ')' for open intervals. I see what's wrong. I didn't include the $\arctan\Big(\frac{4}{3}\Big)$. If the product $\;uv\;>\;1,$ and the sign in the denominator changes, there are two cases: either $u,v\;> 0$ or $u,v\;< 0$, which means $\tan$ is either postive or negative. When proving the statement we add or subtract $\pi$, I have to prove $\arctan\notin \Big(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$ which matters in the restriction?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure quite what your question is, but yes, the upper endpoint of the interval *is* in the range. (In any case, the denominator does not vanish in our particular case.) Which country uses $\langle a, b \rangle$ for an open interval?

Comment: Well, I come from Croatia and I know for sure most of the Eastern European countries. I hadn't known for the other notations before my friends went to study in Austria and Germany.

Comment: I thought if this $uv>1$ and $uv<1$ is only if the $\arctan{u}$ and $\arctan{v}$ aren't complementary, so the restriction doesn't allow that.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by "the restriction doesn't allow that", but see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724348/what-is-arctanx-arctany

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cot^{-1}(\pm \infty)= 0$ and $\tan^{-1} (\pm \infty) =\pm \pi/2$, $\cot^{-1}(0^+)= \pi/2$ so the least value taken by the given function $$f(x)= \cot^{-1}x +\tan^{-1} (1+x)$$ is $-\pi/2$. its (global) maximum value will occur at $x=0$ which is $f(0)=\pi/2+\pi/4= 3\pi/4.$ Sot the range of the given function is $(-\pi/2, 3\pi/4]$

See the attached figure where  $f(0)=3\pi/4=2.3561...$. The upper horizontal line depicts this value and the lower horizontal line depicts the lower bound of $-\pi/2.$

[image]

Comment: The claims about the location of the maximum and the value of the maximum are both incorrect. The maximum occurs at $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ (in fact, the function is symmetric about the line that equation defines), and the maximum value is $\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \arctan \frac{1}{2} = 2.49809\ldots$.

Comment: It's true that some authors define $\operatorname{arccot}$ with a discontinuity at $0$, but OP's assertion of the identity $\arctan x + \operatorname{arccot} x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ means that they are not using such a convention.

Comment: (Also, the numerical approximation cannot be right, since $\frac{3 \pi}{4} < \pi = 3.14159\ldots$.)

Comment: Oh! sorry I meant $f(0)=3\pi/4=2.3561$, this is also the global maximum of $f(x)$, At  $x=-1/2$, there is a local maximum not the global one. I have corrected the the value of $f(0$ in my edit.

Comment: Again, your claim that the global maximum occurs at $x = 0$ and not $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ relies on a convention for $\operatorname{arccot}$ that OP's question makes clear is *not* the one they are using; rearranging the identity in the question statement we can take OP's definition to be $\operatorname{arccot} x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x$). Using OP's convention, the function does not have a jump discontinuity, and the (global) maximum occurs at $x = -\frac{1}{2}$ as mentioned above.