# The identity $\arctan(x) + \arctan(x^3) = \arctan(2x+\sqrt{3}) + \arctan(2x-\sqrt{3})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I came to this identity while doing some indefinite integrals.

$\arctan(x) + \arctan(x^3) = \arctan(2x+\sqrt{3}) + \arctan(2x-\sqrt{3})$

Seems weird to me, no idea why it's correct but it is.

I wonder if there's some geometric or trigonometric reasoning/insight behind it,
say something which can be useful to high-school students for solving some problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1724348) might be relevant (assuming $x\ge 1$).

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\tan^{-1}(A)+\tan^{-1}(B)=\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{A+B}{1-AB} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

> $$\tan^{-1}(x)+\tan^{-1}(x^3)=\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x(1+x^2)}{1-x^4}\right)=\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{1-x^2} \right).$$

> \begin{eqnarray*}\tan^{-1}(2x+\sqrt{3})+\tan^{-1}(2x-\sqrt{3})&=&\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{4x}{1-(4x^2-3)} \right)\\ &=&\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{1-x^2} \right).\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 4):

Taking the tangent of both members,

$$\frac{x+x^3}{1-x\,x^3}=\frac{4x}{1-(4x^2-3)}$$ is an identity. (Simplify $1+x^2$.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative will use complex number

$$
\begin{aligned}
\arg{\left((1+ix)(1+ix^{3})\right)}=\arg{\left((1+i(2x+\sqrt{3}))(1+i(2x-\sqrt{3}))\right)}
\end{aligned}
$$