# Simplifying atan(x)-atan(y)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, substitution

From this [question post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724348/what-is-arctanx-arctany) and this [youtube video "proof"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WphJgVW4Dnw), I am convince that for $x>0$ and $y>0$, the following holds true:
$$
\tan^{-1}(x)-\tan^{-1}(y)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-y}{1+xy}\right)\ \Longleftarrow (Eq.1)
$$
Let $x=\frac{w}{w-a}$ and $y=\frac{w}{w+a}$

Substituting into Eq.1 and simplifying yields:
$$
\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{w-a}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{w}{w+a}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2aw}{2w^{2}-a^{2}}\right)\ \Longleftarrow (Eq.2)
$$

When I 3d plot the LHS and RHS of Eq.2, with w and a respectively on x and y axis, I expect the 2 surfaces should overlap at all value. However, it doesn't. **The question is why don't they overlap (equal to each other for all value)?**
[[image: Plot of LHS and RHS1]
The blue is LHS and magenta is RHS.

**Edit:**
As suggested bym @emacsdrivesmenuts, I'm including the plot for blue minus magenta:
[image: Difference of LHS and RHS]
The plot suggest that indeed, it holds true for w>a.

Comment: To be honest, I'm more interested to whether LHS is equal to RHS for w>a, and both w and a are positive.

Comment: The domain is even more restricted, namely to $w>|a|$.

Comment: Maybe instead of plotting two functions, you can plot their difference?

Comment: I think you are right @emacsdrivesmenuts, it seems to hold for w>|a|.

Comment: See Property set 6 from https://byjus.com/maths/inverse-trigonometric-functions-properties/

Comment: @insipidintegrator, I don't get why it is shifted up by pi. It makes it worse no?

Comment: @John.Apple what’s “worse”?

Comment: Can you provide one numerical value for $x$ and $y$ where your plot mismatches?

Comment: @insipidintegrator never mind, I misunderstood you

Comment: @PC1 It seems that when $w<|a|<\sqrt{2}w$, the mismatches happened. So for example, when a=1.2, w=1, the mismatch happened