# Why is $\int \frac1{\cosh x} dx=2\arctan(\tanh(\tfrac x2))+C$?

Tags: integration, solution-verification

According to WolframAlpha,
$$\int \frac1{\cosh x} dx=2\arctan(\tanh(\tfrac x2))+C$$
On the other hand, easily,
$$\int \frac1{\cosh x} dx=2\int\frac{e^x}{(e^x)^2+1}dx=2\arctan(e^x)+C
$$
I believe that my solution is correct. Does anybody see how WolframAlpha processed and found its solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Both are correct. They differ by a constant. Did you try to plot them?

Comment: Have you tried $u=\tanh\frac{x}{2}$? To relate the two, use a $0$-at-$0$ convention to select $C$ in each, then restate the equivalence using $\tan(r+s)=\frac{\tan r+\tan s}{1-\tan r\tan s}$. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function).

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/htakoofhnh

Comment: Adding to J.G.'s comment: since integrating rational functions of sine and cosine is amenable to the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), it is not out-of-the-blue (given this knowledge) to investigate a hyperbolic version of this substitution. Note the definite integral (starting at $0$) is called the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function).

Comment: Incidentally, computing [the inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function) was an important problem for navigators in the 1600s, made non-trivial by the FTC not having been proved.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I got the difference idea from the plot and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sometimes we get two results to the same problem (specially in integrals) mean this two results (or more) are related (or have common characteristics) and in integrals if you get the same results this mean that you have
$$ f_1(x)+c_1=f_2(x)+c_2$$
for example lets show how to get the wolframs result we have
$$ \cosh^2x+\sinh^2x=\cosh(2x)$$
So
$$ \int \frac{1}{\cosh x}dx=\int \frac{1}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sinh^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}dx=\int \frac{1}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sinh^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\frac{\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}dx$$
then
$$ \int \frac{1}{\cosh x}dx=2\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{1+\tanh^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}dx=2\tan^{-1}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+c$$
and we can see that
$$ 2\tan^{-1}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\right) $$
but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724348/what-is-arctanx-arctany) we have
$$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(x\right)+\tan^{-1}\left(y\right)+a$$
for $a\in \mathbb{R}$ where its value depends on values of $x$ and $y$ , now by putting $x\to e^x$ , $y\to-1$ we get
$$2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\right)=2\tan^{-1}\left(e^x\right)+2\tan^{-1}\left(-1\right)+2a=2\tan^{-1}\left(e^x\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}+2a$$
therefore
$$ 2\tan^{-1}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)=2\tan^{-1}\left(e^x\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}+2a $$
which mean its same result So, we can say

$$ \int \frac{1}{\cosh x}dx=2\tan^{-1}\left(\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+c=2\tan^{-1}\left(e^x\right)+c $$

Answer (score 2):

For any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ it results that

$\begin{align}\arctan\left[\tanh\left(\dfrac x2\right)\right]&=\arctan\left(\dfrac{e^{\frac x2}-e^{-\frac x2}}{e^{\frac x2}+e^{-\frac x2}}\right)=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=\arctan\left(\dfrac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\right)=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=\arctan\left[\dfrac{\tan(\arctan e^x)-\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)}{1+\tan(\arctan e^x)\!\cdot\!\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)}\right]=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=\arctan\left[\tan\left(\arctan\left(e^x\right)-\dfrac\pi4\right)\right]=\\[3pt]&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\overset{\color{blue}{(*)}}{=}\arctan\left(e^x\right)-\dfrac\pi4\;.\end{align}$

The last equality $\,(*)\,$ is a conseguence of the fact that

$\arctan\left(e^x\right)\!-\!\dfrac\pi4\in\left(-\dfrac\pi4,\dfrac\pi4\right)\subseteq\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right)\quad\forall\,x\in\Bbb R$

and the function tangent is invertible on $\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right).$

Since $\;\arctan\left[\tanh\left(\dfrac x2\right)\right]\!=\!\arctan\left(e^x\right)\!-\!\dfrac\pi4\;$ for any $\,x\in\Bbb R$

it follows that OP’s solution is equal to WolframAlpha’s one.

Answer (score 1):

We need to find a function $f=f(x)$ such that
$$\arctan e^x-\arctan f=\text{constant}.$$
Taking tangent of both sides, we have
$$\frac{e^x-f}{1+e^xf}=\text{constant}.$$
Setting constant to $1$ we find
$$f=\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}=\tanh(\tfrac x2).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{1}{\cosh x} \, dx$$

Being  $\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ rewrite the previous integral:

$$\int \frac{1}{\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}} \, dx$$

Multiply the numerator and denominator by $2$:

$$\int \frac{2}{e^x + e^{-x}} \, dx $$

$$\int \frac{2e^x}{e^{2x} + 1} \, dx \tag 1$$

Let $u = e^x$, then $du = e^x \, dx$. Thus from the $(1)$

$$ 2\int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1} \, du= 2\arctan(u) + C=2\arctan(e^x)+C$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.$C'=C$?

Comment: @BobDobbs I have not understood.