# How can I integrate indefinite integral $\int\frac{1}{a+b\sin x}dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried taking hints from this [How do you integrate $\int \frac{1}{a + \cos x} dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134577/how-do-you-integrate-int-frac1a-cos-x-dx) but could not find answer.

I am learning integration from book and youtube videos, so answers with explanation would be of great help to me.

Comment: Use  https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/WeierstrassSubstitution.shtml

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{a+b\sin x} = \frac{1}{b}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac ab + \sin x}$$

Now, use the methods in the question you linked.